# Force relative import with full filename

Tags: typescript, eslint

On my TypeScript project to import `./foo/index.ts` I can use any of these 4 lines:

```js
import Foo from './foo'           // ❌
import Foo from './foo/index'     // ❌
import Foo from './foo/index.js'  // ❌
import Foo from './foo/index.ts'  // ✅
```

I would like to configure my project so that relative imports are only allowed with the full file name and its actual extension.

is there a way to do it with `tsconfig.json` or ESLint?

Answer (score 0):

You can install this:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-require-extensions
or 
yarn add -D eslint-plugin-require-extensions
```

then apply by adding/updating your .eslintrc.json

```
  extends: [
    "plugin:require-extensions/recommended",
  ],
  plugins: ["require-extensions"],
```

Then try with:

```
npm eslint ./src
or 
yarn eslint ./src
```